# Utility Classes of Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Yo guys, i have a vuetify project that i need to change lnline style to utility classes (if possible)

```
font-size: 24px; font-weight :600
```

I saw the documentation that i only saw it set the size and weight without a value, such as `text-h4` or `font-weight-regular`. May i know is it can change to utility classes if i want set the size and weight with value?

example code:

```
<span class="ma-0" style="color: var(--Gray-001, #7f7f7f); font-size: 22px; font-weight :600">Welcome to our shop </span>
```

Comment: Vue provides a set of utility classes for typography, but it does not directly support setting font sizes and weights with specific pixel values. You can achieve then by making a custom class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 ways you can do it.

1. Create custom class
2. Overide vuetify class

We can only override the values of the classes listed in the documentation, you are free to change them as you wish.